# Selecting multiple strings from the output of command in powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-10, powershell-v5.1

This may be a simple question that has been answered before but I just couldn't find it. I am trying to filter out unneeded text/output from a simple script I made.

```
$stop = 2
do {
clear
netstat -a -n -o | Select-String "ESTABLISHED"
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
} while ($stop -ne 1)
```

I want to add more than just established connections to the output window such as both the UDP and TCP connections but remove the loopback addresses. If there is a better way or more efficient way of doing this that would be great.

Comment: Which OS are you on?  May not need to use `netstat`

Comment: I am using Windows 10 currently.

Comment: Then use a better RegEx `netstat -a -n -o | Select-String "UDP|TCP *(?!=127.0.0.1)|ESTABLISHED"` But I'm with @TheIncorrigible1, better use PowerShell cmdlets. before parsing text output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're on Windows 10, you have access to the `Get-NetTCPConnection` cmdlet.  Instead of parsing `netstat` output, you can work with *objects*:

```
Get-NetTCPConnection |
    Where-Object RemoteAddress -notin '127.0.0.1','0.0.0.0', '::'
```

For UDP:

```
Get-NetUDPEndpoint
```